How to send/receive data using CANoe FDX protocol?
I'm trying to send and receive data using CANoe FDX protocol.
I went through this document, which has instructions on how to configure CANoe config file.
I'm using CAPL for automation but I couldn't find the related CAPL functions to send data using FDX, can anyone help me understand, what are the FDX related functions in CAPL.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

To transfer data between CANoe and external server running on UDP you have to configure fdx xml and enable fdx in CANoe options so that it runs as server.
fdx sample
fdx
Based on this you can form a UDP packet and send data you wanted to send to CANoe and vice versa
